# How do I remove the vertical scroll bar on a kendo grid?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am given a js file to look at and trying to figure out how to hide/remove the vertical scroll bar, don't have access to the html/css document and saw I could add css style, but don't know how to put style in just the js file.

The table is larger than the window, but uses the window scroll bar to go up/down and the scroll bar on the grid is useless and just grayed out. I have a horizontal scroll bar that works as intended, so is there a way to get rid of the vertical scroll bar?

Tried looking up online some answers that I couldn't implement such as css style

Answer (score 0):

In your JS file, add a dataBound event handler to the grid and hide the scrollbar on the div with class k-grid-content:

```
dataBound: function(e){
  e.sender.element.find(".k-grid-content").css("overflow-y", "hidden");
}
```

**[DEMO](https://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/IsohadOg)**

or as long as the grid is already initialized, just add that line

```
$("#GridId .k-grid-content").css("overflow-y", "hidden");
```